# MATLAB := Syntax?

Tags: matlab, syntax, wolfram-mathematica

I am having trouble trying to debug some code (new to MATLAB). I have come across the following line of code:

```
CC[theta_] := {{Cos[theta],I Sin[theta]},{I Sin[theta], Cos[theta]}}
```

I get an error stating:

> Parse error at ":": Usage may be invalid MATLAB syntax.

When I remove the `:`, I get the exact same message, just that in this case it says 'Parse error at "="'. Is there any way to fix this? This is fairly old MATLAB code so I'm not sure if the syntax style has changed.

Comment: What exactly you want to do? The code is not at all Matlab-style. CC is a function of theta?

Comment: I think CC is a function of theta. What language does the code resemble? I'm not sure for now what it's trying to be done here since I'm going through it.

Comment: For me its Mathematica.

Comment: @Jommy: Of course it's a Mathematica. CC is a function of theta as well... See my answer for more details and the corresponding solution in Matlab.

Comment: If you are given "MATLAB" code containing :=, it may also be MuPAD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provided code origins clearly from Mathematica. To do the same in Matlab, we can define a function handle:

```
CC = @(theta) [cos(theta), 1i*sin(theta); 1i*sin(theta), cos(theta)]
```

`1i` is the imaginary unit in Matlab (`I` in Mathematica).
Matlab uses `[a,b;c,d]` to define a `2x2`-matrix (`{{a,b},{c,d}}` in Mathematica). The definition `:=` is not possible in Matlab. A function handle (as in the example) or a symbolic function can be used.

Evaluated at `theta=pi/4` with the command `CC(pi/4)` gives this result:

```
 0.7071 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.7071i
 0.0000 + 0.7071i   0.7071 + 0.0000i
```

Comment: You can also just use `i` in Matlab as it is the imaginary unit by default, but I think `1i` is the safer option because Matlab will allow you to overwrite `i` so you can cause problems for yourself if you for example accidentally use it as a loop variable in your code.

Comment: @Dan: That's exactly why I used `1i` . The documentation says: «For speed and improved robustness in complex arithmetic, use 1i and 1j instead of i and j.» Matlab even informs you in the Editor. `i` is used very often in loops, so `1i` is the choice for me.